# Angular 2 Jasmine/Karma Test - file should end with a newline

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I've written a class where I am getting the following warning:

```
WARNING in ./src/app/nav/shared/nav.ts
[15, 4]: file should end with a newline
```

Can't figure error out for the life of me. Anyone know the reason? My class file below:

```
// NavToolItem class
export class NavToolItem {
    view: string;
    name: string;
    icon: string;
    type: string;
    link: string;
    order: number;
}

// Array of Menus
export const NAVTOOLITEMARR: NavToolItem[] = [
 {view: 'Dashboard', name: 'menu', icon: 'fa fa-bars fa-3x', type: 'panel', link: '', order: 0},
 {view: 'Dashboard', name: 'search-employee', icon: 'fa fa-search fa-3x', type: 'panel', link: '', order: 0}
 ];
```

Comment: Do you have a new line at the end of the file? Probably just linting warnings (not an error).

Comment: Unrelated, but good read, see also [Why should text files end with a newline?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/2587435)

Comment: No I don't have new line at the end of the file